# 404 error when using getJSON

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

Hi guys having some trouble here trying to reuse some code here giving to by the owner of the web site . I have a load and save function the save function works fine now but not the load , I keep getting a 404 error even tho the file is there i tried renaming the file , clear cache ect .. Any ideas

```js
$('#btnLoad').click(function(evt) {
  //    empty the list
  $('#selCaseStudies').find('option').remove();

  //    populate the list of case studies
  $.getJSON("dbs/gcsl.php", function(data) {
    $.each(data, function(key, value) {
      //alert(key + ":" + value);
      $('#selCaseStudies').append("<option value='" + key + "'>" + value[1] + "-" + value[2] + "</option>");
    });
  });

  //    show the dialog
  $('#dlgLoad').dialog({
    buttons: {
      "Ok": function() {
        $(this).dialog("close");
        var csd = {};
        csid = $('#selCaseStudies').val();
        //csid = prompt("casestudyid", "1");
        loadCaseStudy(csid);
      },
      "Cancel": function() {
        $(this).dialog("close");
      }
    }
  });

  //    don't call the home button handler
  evt.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: Are you sure it is a valid json output?

Comment: Ya pretty sure the save works fine